# Javascript input field not Working

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to fill an input field, using a javascript, all the script is not working, i only see the echo of the php but not the javascript part that is intended to fill the input field.

this is my code

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$card = $_POST['card'];
echo json_encode(array('card_response' => get_cc_type($card)));
//exit;
}
```

and this my script, but i don't know why its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
var card_value = document.getElementById('card').value; // get the input value
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create the xmlhttprequest object
var params = 'card=' + card_value; // create the query string
var php_url = document.URL; // this is the URL of the PHP, in this example, i'll just setup it the PHP on the same page.
xmlhttp.open('POST', php_url, true); // set as POST

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        // handle the response from server here
        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        document.getElementById('cardtype').value = response.card_response; // set the value
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(params); // execute
 });
 </script>
```

i only see this stuff in my page ---  {"card_response":"VIP"}

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

this is the error when i press the button to validate, and there is no < character on the field or anywhere

Comment: <input type="button" id="button" value="Validar" />

Comment: Can you provide JSON ?

Comment: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$card = $_POST['card'];
echo json_encode(array('card_response' => get_cc_type($card)));
exit;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On jquery first check with an alert

```
alert(xmlhttp.toSource());
alert(response.toSource());

alert(response.card_response);
```

These alerts will tell you what values you are getting exactly.for eg. xmlhttp.status is 200 or not.

Also, check in Firebug, is jquery malfunctioning?

Comment: firebug just tells me SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

response = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: @ManuelPerez     Just insert header type in php code as " header('Content-Type: application/json');  "  before " echo json_encode(array('card_response' => get_cc_type($card)));  ".  And use alert to source on variable "response"

Comment: As you are expecting JSON, You have to mention content-type in both PHP code and in Javascript Ajax

Comment: how to mention that where? im just new to php. I already have this xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: This will help you    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax   and header('Content-Type: application/json'); before sending echo response back to ajax