# Bad request status 400. Required String parameter 'login' is not present

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, httprequest

I am trying to build login with react.js and connect it to my springboot.

Here is my code, react.js:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Login extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        login:"",
        password:""
    }
}

// This will be called when the user clicks on the login button
login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.password)

    function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

            // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
            // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
            xhr.open(method, url, true);

        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

            // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
            // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);

        } else {

            // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
            xhr = null;

        }
        return xhr;
    }

    var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', "http://localhost:8080/test/login");
    if (!xhr) {
        throw new Error('CORS not supported');
    }
        fetch().then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
}

render() {

    return (
        <form role="form">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit"onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

And this is my springboot code that is located as TestController:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/login", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public Boolean testLogin(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String password) {
    if ( login.equals ("ajt"))

    return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Each of them are present in two different ports, react on :9000 and springboot on :8080.

Also, on my react page I get the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.(…)
```

Any ideas?

for info: I have only got 6 months coding behind me -_- please be kind!

Answer (score 0):

There's a handful of small mistakes here.  I'll try to point you in the right direction for a few of them.

First of all, I just wouldn't use `fetch`.  It's [listed as an expiremntal technology by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), and it's browser support is weak.  For someone just starting out with web development, you're much better off using a more established and "safe" technology.  Either simple [XMLHTTP ajax or using the ajax method from jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax).  You already seem to be going down the path of XMLHTTP, so I would suggest just replacing your `fetch` commands with the example I linked above.

Second, you're using two different HTTP methods.  Your ajax object is going to send a `POST` command, but your server is listening for a `GET` command.  This is set up on the following lines;

```
var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', "http://localhost:8080/test/login");
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/login", method = RequestMethod.GET )
```

If you want those two pieces of code to talk to one another, they need to be set to the same method.  In this case, you want a `POST` for both, but it's worth learning [the distinction between the two](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for the future.

Lastly, there's the issue of getting information from your inputs and into your ajax XMLHTTP object.  To do this, you're going to want to set up `onChange` hooks on the inputs, and attach them to a `handleChange` function within the react component.  Use this function to save the values to the component's `state`, and then later take the values out of state to apply to the xmlhttp.

A simple example of what I am describing;

```
render() {

    return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="login" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Login</button>
            </div>
    );
}

handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({login: value});
}

login () {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/test/login");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({login: this.state.login}));
}
```

Comment: so I now get code 400 on spring app because String parameter login is not present; while my react.js app displays `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`. My understanding is that react sees spring but cannot post to it, while spring just cannot receive the login parameter.

Comment: What you're now facing is a CORS issues.  By default, servers do not allow you to access them unless you are coming from something they created.  This is good.  You don't want someone else to write a program that allows them to send login requests to your system.  However, it's an issue for you because your react and api components are hosted on different hosts (locahost:8080 vs localhost:9000).  To fix this, you will need to tell your api to allow incoming requests from localhost:9000; `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")`

Comment: I have actually overcome the issue via a CORSFilter that was submitted by someone (I also tried that option and for some reason went for the previous one). So, now when I submit from reactjs app I get error 400 (OK) in red, but that activates my console from the Spring application and triggers `Required String parameter 'login' is not present`. So I feel that now they are connected, but that either the info is not well sent via react or the reception from spring is not well coded.