# Trying to parse JSON Object from POST Request in Express v4 using body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, body-parser

I'm currently teaching myself more about server code, specifically using Node.js and Express, and I'm having a lot of trouble with receiving and parsing a JSON object sent from a POST request. I have looked at numerous other posts (linked to below) and I can't figure out for the life of me what's going wrong. Here's what I've looked at:

Javascript: Send JSON Object with AJAX
[Javascript : Send JSON Object with Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax)
How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application
[How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application)
Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest
[Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)
How do you extract POST data in Node.js?
[How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

All of these are putting me on the right track, but I'm not quite there and thus looking for help. Here's the code I'm working with:

**Send POST Request**

```
var button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.onclick = function(){
    console.log("Getting data from local server");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/data/test.json", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"latitude": 41.2418, "longitude": -70.8898}));
};
```

**Handle POST Request In Server**

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
//tells express where to find all the static files (HTML, CSS, etc) and load them into the browser
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));

//tells the application to use body-parser as middleware so it can handle post requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routing methods
//deal with incoming GET and POST requests to the server
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send("Submitted GET Request");
})

//only handles incoming POST requests to the test.json resource
app.post("/data/test.json", function(req, res){
    console.info("Submitting POST Request to Server");
    console.info("Request body: " + req.body);
    //write the file
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/../client/data/test.json", req.body, 
    function(err){
        if(err){
            console.error(err); //print out the error in case there is one
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }

        //resolve the request with the client
        console.info("updated test.json");
        res.send();
    });
})

//tell the express object to create the server and listen on the port
app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on localhost:" + port);
```

Whenever I try to print out the contents of "req.body" I get the output of "[object Object]". Any ideas?

EDIT: 
My issue has been solved. I have changed

```
console.info("Request body: " + req.body);
```

To

```
console.info("Request body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

I also changed my Content-Type in my POST XMLHTTPRequest to "application/json" to help with formatting.

Comment: uh... your content type doesn't match your data... ???

Comment: Try this JSON.stringify(req.body);

Comment: [object object] means that the variable you are trying to print isn't a string, easy fix just use JSON.stringify(req.body);

Comment: @KevinB I thought I could use "application/json" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" interchangeably based on looking at different posts, but this was definitely a part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"[object Object]"` is the default result of JavaScript's implicit `toString` operation, which it uses when trying to write a string representation of that object to the file.

Try writing `JSON.stringify(req.data)` to the file instead.

Also, on the client side – consider changing your `Content-Type` header to match:

`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Answer (score 0):

If your post body is expected to be JSON, then change this line

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

To

```
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Didn't help the [object Object] issue, but fixed the formatting of my JSON object.