# middleware not working when placed in if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {              
  if (req.originalUrl === '/stripewebhook') {
         next();
   } else {
          bodyParser.json();
          bodyParser.urlencoded({
              extended: true })(req, res, next);

         }
   });
```

But this works!

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {          
  if (req.originalUrl === '/stripewebhook') {
         next();
   } else {
          bodyParser.json()(req, res, next);
          bodyParser.urlencoded({
              extended: true });

         }
   });
```

My original code was just the two bodyParsers middleware:

```
 ......
    ......
    bodyParser.json();
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
                  extended: true });
    .....
```

I needed to add the if statement so that the webhook endpoint is skipped but I noticed that I had to set the statements like the above working example...what I am not sure about is if the .urlencoded() ever get executed??

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the Content Type of the Header may be not matching. You may take a look at this documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html. 
and also regarding the implementation: [Trying to parse JSON Object from POST Request in Express v4 using body-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378391/trying-to-parse-json-object-from-post-request-in-express-v4-using-body-parser)

Answer (score 1):

In node.js, middlewares like `bodyParser.json()` return functions. If the returned functions are not called, their behaviour does not apply.

The usual way to use them is to give their return values to `app.use()`.

To have a conditional use of a middleware based on the route url, you can do something like:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
// specific router handling only your conditional middlewares
router.use(bodyParser.json())
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
// only call this router if the url is not /stripewebhook
app.use(/^(?!\/stripewebhook)/, router)

// [...] all your app-related middlewares
```

Of course this may not be the solution to your root issue regarding the stripe web hook.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation above....from my understanding the fact the I am already wrapping the bodyParser in app.use function should take care of the return to the App. ...

Comment: This is actually my root issue...the If statement took care of the webhook requirement of getting a rawBody...so my concern is what happens when the url is not webhook.

Comment: My main question was about ensuring that the .urlencoded(..) also get executed...are you saying that router.use() won't get executed until placed in the app.use() function?

Comment: You should refer to the express documentation about how to use middlewares https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html