# ExpressJS ajax sending empty data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to send JSON to my server, but the POST requests are appearing with an empty body. Here is my typescript on the front end:

```
function sendData() : void {
console.log("Sending data...");
var name_ : string = (document.getElementById("name") as HTMLInputElement).value;
var id_ : string = (document.getElementById("series") as HTMLInputElement).value;

var toSend = new FormData();
toSend.append("name",name_);
toSend.append("id",id_);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/add");
request.send(toSend);

}
```

My server has this code: I've omitted the file paths.

```
var Express = require('express');
var BodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Multer = require('multer');
var app = Express();
var upload = Multer();

app.use(Express.static("/public"));
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(BodyParser.json());

app.get('/public/dataAjax.js', function(req,res){
res.sendFile("C:\\<omitted>\\dataAjax.js");
})

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile("C:\\<omitted>\\index.html");
});

app.post('/add', function(req,res) {
  console.log("Received:");
  console.log(req);
  res.status(201).json(req.body.name);
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("Running on port 8000!"));
```

My problem appears to be entirely server side, as I've used flask in the past and this code worked fine. My focus here is using node with expressjs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : Send JSON Object with Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only parses a request with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#type-3) of body parser.

```
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

`FormData` sends the request with `Content-Type` set as `multipart/form-data`.
As your bodyparser can't parse such content type, you should try to send the data either as `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
See MDN docs of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

You can use jquery's [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to get the urlencoded string.