# router.post can't pass data

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post

```
$.post($gameNetwork._serverURL+'/addfriend', 
{username:"r",tusername:"w"}).done(function (data) {
console.log("finished");
 });



Account.statics.

    friend = function(name,tname,cb) {

        return this.findOneAndUpdate(

        { 'username':  name },

        { $push: {'friendlist': tname}},


        { upsert: true, new: true}, 

        cb);

    };
```

route

```
router.post('/addfriend',  function(req, res) {

//Account.findByName(req.body.username, function(err, account){
    Account.friend(req.body.username,req.body.tusername, function(err, account){
 if (err) {
      return res.status(203).json({
        err: err.msg
      });}
    if (!account) {
      return res.status(203).json({
        err: "Invalid username"
      });}
        var tname = req.body.tusername;

    var profile = {
        tname : tname,
      name: account.username,
      email: account.email,
      id: account._id,
      rank: account.rank
    };  });
```

this code should enter "w" in to the field 'friendlist' in Mongodb,  but I got null instead of w.

how can I get "w" into the field 'friendlist' in Mongodb.
Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: The very first step is always to do some basic debugging. If you add `console.log(req.body);` can you see what you expect to see?

Comment: I restarted the server and browser and everything works fine

Comment: thanks for all comments

Answer (score 0):

`router` in an ExpressJS `router`?

If yes did you set the `bodyParser` middleware?

If not, set it like this

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

You can also try to stringify the body in the ajax request like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your data of request like this:

```
router.post('/addfriend',  function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // your logic
}
```

Run your code again, and you can see your data that you expect. If you see **tusername = null or undefined**, may be the problem in configure of your module that you use, example *body-parser*, *busboy*...vv

All comments are welcome!