# Extracting Data from Ajax Request in Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am unsure how to extract data from an Ajax request from my Javascript code in a python application in Flask. My Ajax request does not use jQuery.

I have tried using `request.form.get()` and `request.get_json()` in my Python code but both produce a `None` value.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if not request.get_json() == None: 
        print(request.get_json())
        name = request.get_json()
        session["name"] = name.user
    return render_template("index.html", channels=channels)
```

In my Javascript code I perform a simple Ajax request:

```
    if(localStorage.getItem("user")) {
        document.querySelector("#logout").addEventListener("click", () => {
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
        })

        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/")
        user = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("user"))
        request.send(user)
    }
```

Comment: related: [jQuery posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json), [Send JSON data with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery), and [Send JSON Object with Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax)

Comment: I am not using jQuery

Comment: I know. They're related, not duplicates. Check out the last one, though.

Comment: Thanks but the last one doesn't show what to do at the Flask end

Comment: I think you should use the [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify) function to return json response from your flask api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be coming in `request.get_data()` not in `request.get_json()`

refer [request.get_json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json) & 
[request.get_data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_data) for more info

Comment: If your request type is application/json it will come under request.get_json() in your case you haven't mentioned any request type it should be coming in request.get_data()

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it clearly you don't want to send the whole dictionary like `('user':'value')` only the value.

In this case `request.get_data()` works just fine in this case:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    data = open('index.html').read()
    print request.get_data()
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

index.html is a simple page with a button which triggers the following javascript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open("POST","/", true)
var send_data = "Hello World"
request.send(send_data)
```