# Ajax Post Request with Flask

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, flask

I am using AJAX to send a POST request to a Flask route, but I don't know how to get the post data in a format I can read.

My route looks like this:

```
@app.route("/sendinvites", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def sendinvites():
    print(request.get_data("emails"))
    return jsonify("done")
```

My AJAX looks as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/sendinvites",
    data: { emails : emails, usernames: usernames  },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
```

An example of the data sent in the emails variable is:

```
0: Object { id: undefined, username: "me@mydomain.com" }
```

An example of the output from the route is:

```
b'emails%5B0%5D%5Busername%5D=me%40mydomain.com'
```

Does anyone know how I can get the post data into a dictionary object so it is easier to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but first, verify that the request contains a valid JSON.

1. `request.get_json()`

```py
request.get_json(silent=True)
```

With `silent=True` set, the `get_json` function will fail silently when trying to retrieve the JSON body. By default, this is set to `False`.

2. `jsonify(request.json)`

This will return the entire `request` object. You'll have to extract the required part by specifying the key posted while sending the `request` in your ajax code.

Refer this for Flask part, [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask)

Refer this for Ajax part, [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax)