# how do I pass a html table to my flask app

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I am making a flask app, where the user inputs data, and a javascript function adds that data to a  html table and diplays it to the user. I now want to take that table, and send it to my flask app, so it can be added to a database and the sorts. How do I send an html table to my flask app?

here is my code so far:

newroster.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
<form method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="return false;" name="myform">
    <table id="people" class="tablex">
        <tr>
            <th> People </th>
            <th>   </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <label for="people"> Participants</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="people" id="inputpeople" maxlength="15"
        placeholder="Name"
        value="{{ request.form['people']}}"></input>
    <button type="button" id="addButton" class="button" name="add" onclick="addPeopleFunc()">
        Add
    </button>
    <button id="button1" class="button" type="button" name="submitx" value="Submit form" 
    onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function addPeopleFunc() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputpeople").value;
    const inputA = document.getElementById("inputpeople");
    if (input) {
        var table = document.getElementById("people");
        var newrow = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell0 = newrow.insertCell(0);
        var cell1 = newrow.insertCell(1);
        cell0.innerHTML = input;
        cell1.innerHTML = '<button class="button" type="button" name="dellrow" onclick="dellListFunc(this)">Delete';
        inputA.value = '';
    }
}

function submitForm() {
    people = document.getElementById("people");
    data = tableToJson(people);
    console.log(data);

}
```

flask:

```
@app.route('/new-roster', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def newroster():
    return render_template('newroster.html')
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Add a POST route to send the data to and make a fetch request to that endpoint with your JSON.

Comment: @ggorlen could I get a bit more info on this? or could you piont me in the right direction to find out more about this?

Comment: Ass a general rule, is not a good idea. Is better to have o javascript object with the people data, modify that and create your html table based on that. When you want to send the data to flask, just send the javascript object as json.

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard how would one send the javascript object as  json

Comment: There are multiple ways, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax. Flask documentation would be useful too https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/javascript/