# How to handle 2 sets of JSON data passed by AJAX to a PHP script

Tags: php, json, ajax

This is my first toe-dip into the world of JSON/AJAX

Basically I need to pass 2 sets of data to a PHP file. One set is used for saving in a MySQL table, the secons set is ued by the PHP script.

My Javascript produces 2 sets of data which are formatted as JSON strings:

The first is in the format:  `[7,6]`

which consists of 2 variables that will be used by the PHP file, but not related to the main data set.

The second data set consists of n arrays each of which  contains three variables used to update the table:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "stringvar": "string",
        "date": "08/11/2023"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "stringvar": "another string",
        "date": ""
    }
]
```

I have been reading and it would appear I have 2 options:

1. to pass the 2 sets of data as separate sets contained within a single JSON object by stringifying the 2 arrays sparately  then combining in the send:

   ```
    var data1 = JSON.stringify(txt);
   ```

   ```
    var data2 = JSON.stringify(txt1);
   ```

   ```
   xhr.send({data1,data2});
   ```
2. to combine them into a single JSON array:

   ```
   [
       {
           "a": 7,
           "b": 6
       },
       {
           "id": 1,
           "stringvar": "string",
           "date": "08/11/2023"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "stringvar": "another string",
           "date": ""
       }
   ]
   ```

I have tried posting each set individually, and have no trouble extracting the first set into 2 PHP variables, and the second set extracting and writing to the table.

Therefore my problem is handling the data when both sets are sent, so my questions are:

1. which is the best way passing both sets of data at once? (by best I mean most efficient - if it is not one of the above please tell me!)
2. how should the PHP handle the splitting of the passed data?

Comment: If you're sending the request with Content-Type: application/json then you need to send one single JSON object or array. PHP can easily decode the JSON and then you just get the first bit of data from the first array index, and the second from the second index. This IMO also makes more logical and semantic sense than sending two separate JSON objects embedded inside traditional form-url-encoded variables. Mixing data formats rarely ends well. At the very least it adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Relevant: [Javascript : Send JSON Object with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax) and then [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: P.S. `{ "a": 7, "b": 6 }` isn't really the same as `[7, 6]`...it's unclear why you altered it when putting it into the combined array.

Comment: P.P.S. When sending it together, you must combine the datasets using JS, and only `stringify` the final combined result. Don't stringify each bit separately, that won't work properly.

Comment: I changed it because JSONLint wouldn't accept the combined object without the "a" and "b". If I just pass the array in either format I can assign the correct values to the PHP variables the PHP script uses.

Comment: Not sure what you tested, but I just put `[[7,6],{"id":1,"stringvar":"string","date":"08/11/2023"},{"id":2,"stringvar":"another string","date":""}]` into JSONLint and it's completely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would combine them in a container object so you can use named keys for each part.

```
var response = {
    "txt": txt,
    "txt1": txt1
};
var data = JSON.stringify(response);
xhr.send(data);
```